# setInterval being skipped the first call and Clearinterval not stopping when called Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to create a timer that every second it does calls another function. So I am using setInterval within a for loop.

The setInterval is being skipped during the first loop through in the for loop.
Not sure why.

Also,
I have the function to clear the Interval when it goes below zero. When I have a message printing within the stopping condition, that outputs but the clearInterval is skipped.

```js
function changesystem(lottery, maxroundtime, firstloop) {
  //loop through lottery numbers
  for (var keys in lottery) {
    var currentnum = lottery[keys].LotteryNum;
    console.log(currentnum);
    var currentclass = lottery[keys].ClassID;

    //console.log(currentclass);

    //display values
    $('#CurrentNumber').text(currentnum);
    $('#CurrentClass').text(currentclass);

    //change progress bar
    //every second until reaches max round time

    // var loopcontrol = maxroundtime;
    var loopcontrol = 5;
    var timerloop = setInterval(function() {

      console.log(loopcontrol);

      //changetime(maxroundtime,firstloop);
      loopcontrol--;
      //firstloop=1;  

    }, 1000);

    if (loopcontrol < 0) {
      clearInterval(timerloop);
    }
  }
```

[Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wektt.png)

Comment: your var `timerloop` is clobbered by each iteration of your for loop

Comment: The indentation is clobbered too...

Comment: I think you may assume that `setInterval` waits somehow for the seconds to pass, but it doesn't, the `for` loop will go through all iterations immediately, having created just as many `setInterval` timers, which all start to tick and will continue to do so for ever. The `clearInterval` code will never get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account that asynchronous code does not stop the current execution-code. The callback function you pass to `setInterval` is called asynchronously, i.e. *after* the currently being executed code has finished until the point the call-stack is empty.

So `setInterval` does not wait somehow for the seconds to pass. The `for` loop will go through all iterations immediately, having created just as many `setInterval` timers, which all start to tick *afterwards*, and will continue to do so for ever. The `clearInterval` code will never get executed.

Here is how you could do it, making use of asynchronous "loops", i.e. with functions that that get called several times, asynchronously.

```
function changesystem(lottery,maxroundtime,firstloop){
    //loop asynchronously through lottery numbers
    (function loop(keys) {
        if (!keys.length) return; // all done
        var key = keys.shift(); // extract next key
        var currentnum = lottery[key].LotteryNum;
        console.log('lottery number', currentnum);
        var currentclass = lottery[key].ClassID;
        //display values
        $('#CurrentNumber').text(currentnum);
        $('#CurrentClass').text(currentclass);
        //change progress bar asynchronously 
        //every second until reaches max round time
        (function progress(loopControl) {
            console.log('loopControl', loopControl);
            if (!loopControl) {
                loop(keys); // done: continue with next lottery number
            } else { // schedule next progress tick
                setTimeout(progress.bind(null, loopControl-1), 1000);
            }
        })(5); // start with loopControl 5
    })(Object.keys(lottery)); // pass all keys
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I did not realize that was what was happening the way I had it before.